How to Check and find Null values in a column in a pandas dataframe and create a CSV log file and write the null value details in log file?
Hi I have a dataframe as below read
Code  region  role  type

23.    AA.     B.    Y

34.    BB.     C.    X

NaN.   Cc.     A.    Z

56.    BB.     C.    Y

67.    45.     C.    Y.

I need to check if there is any Null/NaN in the 'Code' column and of present We need to create a log file in csv/xlsx and log which row has the null details in log file. Else if no null/NaN is present then print('validation successful '). Using python 3.6 pls help
I tried isnull().value.any()
To find the nulls and checked with if . Used csv write as well But then got stuck .
If the check is successful no null is there the we need to load the file I a MySQL table with connnecting to the db.
Need this in the esle part

What is written to file? Row with data? Position of NaNs/Nulls ?

Welcome to SO! "but then got stuck"? Please be specific in both your expected output and your actual problem, with your actual code. Use tips from [answer]. Don't keep us guessing.

If need write to file positions (index) of rows with missing values use:
import  csv

#test one column
m = df['Code'].isna()
#test any columns
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)

if m.any():
    with open("out.csv","w") as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
        wr.writerow(df.index[m])
else:
    print('validation successful ')

If need write all data with missing values simplier is use pandas:
#test one column
m = df['Code'].isna()
#test any columns
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)

if m.any():
    df[m].to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
else:
    print('validation successful ')

Or if need write to csv it is possible, but in my opinion overcomplicated:
import  csv

#test one column
m = df['Code'].isna()
#test any columns
m = df.isna().any(axis=1)

if m.any():
    with open("out.csv","w", newline='') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)
        wr.writerow(df.columns)
        for val in df[m].to_numpy():
            wr.writerow(val)
else:
    print('validation successful ')


Hi but the file that is created is not getting saved anywhere in the system unable to find it. Pls suggest

#Something like this:

data # your DataFrame
nanrows = [] # list to collect rows with nan
    for i in range(len(data)):
       if data.iloc[i, 0] != data.iloc[i, 0]: # for NaN it will be True.
            nanrows.append(data.iloc[i])
    
# tocsv
nanrows = pd.DataFrame(nanrows)
nanrows.to_csv("nanrows.csv", index=False)


Welcome to SO! You do use a funny trick, but Python has functions for NaN detection that make it unnecessary. Also as OP's question is by SO standards unclear (no code, no specific problem, no specific expected output), I would strongly recommend asking for clarifications before committing to an answer.
